# Javascript, Accordion not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

So I have a very weird tasks to create a `Pure Vanilla Javascript` widget to generate a webpage.

I was given an element to work from, but keep in mind I cannot use any `jQuery` or inline JS or external CSS or create my own `<style></style>` tags.

So I have an accordion that works on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari.

this is a link to js fidle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhf1gp2g/1/ .Can someone explain maybe some of the JS properties are not accessible in Safari?

Not tested in latest IE as well, maybe it's not working there too.

```js
//global variables, html containers
var parentElement, headingContainer, headingImgContainer, headerTextContainer, TopCont;

//html elements for header
var headerH2, headerP;

//html elements for Top container
var TopContH2, TopContP, TopContP2, TopContP3;

//Accordion elements
var accordion, accordionCss, accordionCssAfter, accordionCssActive;

//images
var headingImg;

var cssDown, cssUp;
// create main HTML markup for main element
parentElement = document.getElementById('mainContent');
parentElement.style.borderLeft = 'none';
parentElement.style.paddingRight = '20px';

// Create Accordion 
// #dd6580, #eaeaea
function createAccordion() {
  accordion = document.createElement('div');
  accordion.id = 'accordion';
  accordion.style.padding = '20px';
  accordionCss = "font-size: 16px; padding: 15px; background: #eaeaea;text-align: left; width: 100%; border: 0; transition: .2s";


  accordion.innerHTML = '<button class="accordion" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 15px; background: #eaeaea;text-align: left; width: 100%; border: 0; transition: .2s">Should I choose red or white wine for my wedding <span class="triangle" style="' + cssDown + '"></span></button>' +
    '<div class="panel" style="overflow: hidden; transition: 0.2s ease-in-out; max-height: 0; opacity: 0;">' +
    '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<button class="accordion" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 15px; background: #eaeaea;text-align: left; width: 100%; border: 0; transition: .2s">Should I choose red or white wine for my wedding<span class="triangle" style="' + cssDown + '"></span></button>' +
    '<div class="panel" style="overflow: hidden; transition: 0.2s ease-in-out; max-height: 0; opacity: 0;">' +
    '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>' +
    '</div>';

  parentElement.appendChild(accordion);

  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

  for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (this.nextSibling.style.opacity === "0") {
        this.style.background = "#dd6580";
        this.style.color = "#ffffff";
        this.nextSibling.style = "opacity: 1; transition: 0.2s ;max-height: 500px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;";
        this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style = cssUp;
      } else {
        this.style.color = "#000000";
        this.nextSibling.style = cssPanelHide;
        this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style = cssDown;
        this.style.background = "#eaeaea";
      }
    });
  }
}
cssDown = "width: height: 0px; border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-top: 10px solid #bababa;  position: absolute; right: 50px; margin-top: 5px;";
cssUp = "width: 0px; height: 0px;  border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff; position: absolute; right: 50px;";
cssPanelHide = "overflow: hidden; transition: 0.2s ease-in-out; max-height: 0; opacity: 0;";
cssPanelShow = "opacity: 1; transition: 0.2s ;max-height: 500px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;";


createAccordion();
```

```css
#mainContent {
  width: 691px;
  float: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 20px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent"></div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not just at jsfiddle. You can use [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) to make it executable, like jsfiddle.

Comment: What debugging have you done so far to try to solve this? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The problem is this line: `this.nextSibling.style = "opacity: 1; transition: 0.2s ;max-height: 500px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;";`. See the linked question for the correct way to do it.